# Largest Possible number from given numbers.(Alternative), Greedy Algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, math, greedy

For example, if the input digits are `4 9 3 7`(for n=4) answer is `9743`

1 ≤  ≤ 100, 1 ≤  ≤ 10^4 for all 1 ≤  ≤ .

```
n = int(input())
integers = list(map(int, input().split()))
# integers.sort()

answer = ''

def is_greater_or_equal(max_int, integer):

  len_diff = len(str(max_int)) - len(str(integer))

  if len_diff > 0:
    integer = int(str(integer) + str(integer%10)*len_diff)

    return integer >= max_int

  else:
    len_diff = abs(len_diff)
    max_int = int(str(max_int) + str(max_int%10)*len_diff)

    return integer >= max_int


while len(integers) != 0:
  max_int = 0

  for integer in integers:

    if is_greater_or_equal(max_int, integer) :
      max_int = integer

  answer += str(max_int)
  integers.remove(max_int)

print(int(answer))
```

Greedy Approach: Find the custom_maximum(e.g 56>(5=55)>54 which is done by function is_greater_or_equal() but comparing two numbers at a time) number and append it to `answer` string and remove from the input list

Sub problem: Find custom_max from the list with reduced size at each iteration

`is_greater_or_equal()` gives a correct output when used as standalone, but the above code as a whole fails

I have the following questions :

1. In the case of 5 and 55, which one should be prioritized (i think it depends on other numbers in the list but I am not clear how)?
2. Why is looping or sorting failing and how to fix it?

Consider input:

```
4
10 1000 100 1
# this works if integers.sort(reverse=True)

4
100 10 899 89
# fails for integers.sort(reverse=True)
```

If I sort(no matter ascending or descending) the input array, it still fails in some cases.

NOTE 1)I am aware of comparing two concatenated numbers approach but I want to know if it is possible to solve by the above approach. 2) This is not homework or formal-task.

Comment: What is the expected output for an example input? What is a custom_maximum?

Comment: @Stefan I have edited for explaining custom_maximum as better I can. I don't know the correct answers to the mentioned inputs but it should be 1101001000 and 8998910100.